# Property showing up in crawled properties selection (Search)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, web-crawler

I have user profile property called "Chapter". It is index when it was created. But this property is not showing up on crawled properties selection window to make *MetaData Property Mapping*  for searching. How can I get this property on crawled properties selection window?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I got it this. I made property policy setting to "Every One" and then crawled. after that it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need data in the `Chapter` property for at least one person and then run an incremental crawl.

Comment: I have 14000 persons have this 'Chapter' value. I did couple of times with full and incremental crawl.

Comment: Hmm. I'm trying it out right now. I was sure that was all that you needed to do...

Comment: Hey, I got it this. I made property policy setting to "Every One" and then crawled. after that it works fine.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it figured out.